# GAWK: Inverse of strftime() - Convert date string to seconds since epoc timestamp using format pattern

Tags: linux, shell, gawk

Gnu AWK provides the built in function

```
strftime()
```

which can convert a timestamp like `1359210984` into `Sat 26. Jan 15:36:24 CET 2013`.
I couldn't find a function that would do this:

```
seconds = timefromdate("Sat 26. Jan 15:36:24 CET 2013", "%a %d. %b %H:%M:%S CET %Y")
```

or

```
seconds = timefromdate("2013-01-26 15:36:24", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Whereas `seconds` then is `1359210984`.

So, the date string should be convertable by a format pattern.

I'd like to do this in gawk only.

## Edit 1:

I'd like to convert the date only in gawk for further processing of the stream.

## Edit 2:

I've clarified my question. It was a bit sloppy in the "would do this" code example.

Comment: I think your best chance is to massage the time string by regexps until it becomes acceptable for `mktime`.

Comment: @svnpenn: Nothing's wrong with `date -d`, but it doesn't help filtering a logfile's timestamp. ;) @Anton Kovalenko: I treat this as "there's no such built in function, but ...". I can live with your answer, if you like, you might add it as an answer.

Comment: Clarified my question with precise examples. (I admit, it was a bit sloppy :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function you're looking for is called `mktime()`. You should use the `gensub()` function to manipulate the datespec into the format that can be read by `mktime()`.

---

To format the second example that you give, consider:

```
BEGIN {
    t = "2013-01-26 15:36:24"
    f = "\\1 \\2 \\3 \\4 \\5 \\6"

    s = mktime(gensub(/(....)-(..)-(..) (..):(..):(..)/, f, "", t))

    print s
}
```

Results on my machine:

```
1359178584
```

---

To format the first example that you give, consider:

```
BEGIN {
    t = "Sat 26. Jan 15:36:24 CET 2013"

    gsub(/\.|:/, FS, t)
    split(t,a)

    Y = a[8]
    M = convert(a[3])
    D = a[2]

    h = a[4]
    m = a[5]
    s = a[6]

    x = mktime(sprintf("%d %d %d %d %d %d", Y, M, D, h, m, s))

    print x
}

function convert(month) {

    return(((index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec", month) - 1) / 3) + 1)
}
```

Results on my machine:

```
1359178584
```

---

For more information, please consult the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), specifically [time functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html) and [string functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html). HTH.

Comment: Great answer. I like your `convert()` solution it's very elegant. Mine looked like `MAP["Jan"]="01"; MAP["Feb"]="02"; ... MAP[match[3]] ...` (`match` = `a` in your case) which worked fine but is a bit long.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the python method strptime from datetime:

```
from datetime import datetime

date_string = "21 June, 2018"

print("date_string =", date_string)
print("type of date_string =", type(date_string))

date_object = datetime.strptime(date_string, "%d %B, %Y")

print("date_object =", date_object)
print("type of date_object =", type(date_object))
```

for more info please see here:
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strptime