# Sort rows based on time present in AM/PM format in first column

Tags: linux, shell, sorting, date, scripting

My file contains

```
02:24:01 PM|7.76636|0.0481818|4.02818|0.0827273|0|0.0354545|0|0|88.0382
12:48:01 PM|8.00364|0.0509091|4.14545|0.0836364|0|0.0381818|0|0|87.6809
05:30:01 AM|9.23909|0.0572727|4.73545|0.0881818|0|0.04|0|0|85.8364
```

Expected Output

```
05:30:01 AM|9.23909|0.0572727|4.73545|0.0881818|0|0.04|0|0|85.8364
12:48:01 PM|8.00364|0.0509091|4.14545|0.0836364|0|0.0381818|0|0|87.6809
02:24:01 PM|7.76636|0.0481818|4.02818|0.0827273|0|0.0354545|0|0|88.0382
```

Tried out almost every options.
Can Anybody suggest what to do over here.

Comment: I would implement this in gawk; better time parsing there, and you can provide your own comparator for sorting.

Comment: That said, the difficulty you're having with this should make it clear why it's important to use `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SSZ` in the future, so an ASCII sort does the right thing.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Is that a GNU awk extension? And awk doesn't have sorting.

Comment: ...the duplicate I closed with this doesn't actually have any answers using awk -- note that anything calling `$(date ...)` once per line is going to be really slow -- but they should very much be adaptable to your use case.

Comment: @Barmar, gawk supports sorting. Turns out I was wrong thinking it had strptime, though; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14537954/gawk-inverse-of-strftime-convert-date-string-to-seconds-since-epoc-timestam covers transforming a string with a date in a different format to one it can parse.

Comment: I'm going to underscore the `YYYY-MM-DD....` point.  it's called ISO 8601 format  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 and it's lexiconographic order is the same as chronological order, which really simplifies sorting lists.  Of course this only works if you put all the dates in the same time zone - UTC is the preferred choice for that.   Also an easy way to end the "us vs european date format" debate - they're both wrong!

Comment: `strptime` is gawk (gnu awk) specific extension https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html.