# Iterate over dates in given interval with format like 20231205203830

Tags: bash

I need to iterate over dates in a given interval, where dates have format 20231205203830 (5 of December, 2023 20:38:30). I can't change the format.

I tried formatting the date with the following command

```
FROM=$(date -d '20231205203830' +'+%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
```

But it gives me `date: invalid date ‘20231205203830’`.

I want to have a `$TO` variable representing the end of the interval and iterate from `$FROM` to `$TO` in a manner like here:

```
while (( $(date -d "${FROM}" +%s) <= $(date -d "${TO}" +%s) )); do
    ...
done
```

Can this be done with the given format? If so - how could I form the loop?

Comment: Partitionate your string into its pieces (2023, 12, 05, 20, 38, 30). Then do with these pieces whatever you want.

Comment: From your description it is not clear to me over which timepoints the loop is supposed to iterate. One per day? One per second?

Comment: please update the question with a sample set of `${FROM}`, `${TO}` and some indication of the loop interval (seconds? mins? hours? days? months? something else?)

Comment: Don't use all upper case for non-exported variable names, see [correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to split the different digits into groups with Bash's built-in Regex like this:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

iDate=20231205203830

[[ $iDate =~ ([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2}) ]] || :

iY=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
im=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
id=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
iH=${BASH_REMATCH[4]}
iM=${BASH_REMATCH[5]}
iS=${BASH_REMATCH[6]}

date --date "$iY-$im-$id $iH:$iM:$iS"
```

Alternatively, the string can be indexed like this:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

iDate='20231205203830'

iY=${iDate:0:4}
im=${iDate:4:2}
id=${iDate:6:2}
iH=${iDate:8:2}
iM=${iDate:10:2}
iS=${iDate:12:2}

date --date "$iY-$im-$id $iH:$iM:$iS"
```

Finally, when Bash is not available, the POSIX shell grammar will allow splitting date elements by using arithmetic:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh

iDate='20231205203830'

iY=$((iDate/10000000000))
im=$((iDate/100000000 - iY * 100))
id=$((iDate/1000000 - iY * 10000 - im * 100))
iH=$((iDate/10000 - iY * 1000000 - im * 10000 - id * 100))
iM=$((iDate/100 - iY * 100000000 - im * 1000000 - id * 10000 - iH * 100))
iS=$((iDate - iY * 10000000000 - im * 100000000 - id * 1000000 - iH * 10000 - iM * 100))

date --date "$iY-$im-$id $iH:$iM:$iS"
```

Alternate POSIX shell method using parameter expansion, to slice out unwanted leading and trailing characters of the input date string:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh

iDate='20231205203830'

iY=${iDate%??????????}
im=${iDate#????} im=${im%????????}
id=${iDate#??????} id=${id%??????}
iH=${iDate#????????} iH=${iH%????}
iM=${iDate#??????????} iM=${iM%??}
iS=${iDate#????????????}

date --date "$iY-$im-$id $iH:$iM:$iS"
```

Comment: Or you could avoid the arithmetic expressions and use simple [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to split off `n` digits from the beginning of the string (four, then successively two more until you have consumed it all).

Comment: @tripleee I can't see how I'd use parameter expansion without Bash indexing capabilities here.

Comment: Yeah, fair. I started to think about an implementation but didn't get too far.

Comment: @tripleee added POSIX parameter-expansion method.

Comment: Excellent! I tried to get fancy and use a function but there is no sane way to do that.

Answer (score 3):

The `+` format specifier only selects the *output* date format; but your format is easy enough to parse into the required pieces.

Assuming you have the start date and time in `$1`, try

```
from=$(date -d "${1:0:4}-${1:4:2}-${1:6:2} ${1:8:2}:${1:10:2}:${1:12:2}" +%s)
```

You'll note that I chose the machine-readable Unix epoch `+%s` in favor of the unwieldy display format you want. (Also note, there should only be one `+` before the format specifier, unless you really want a literal plus sign at the start of the value.)

It's much easier to loop over that, and easy enough to convert it to your desired format at any time;

```
date -d "@$from" +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S'
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/TmZkSE

Of course, if what happens inside the `while` loop also needs to manipulate data in the display format, it can be done, at the expense of complicating the code. I'm also wondering why you are using `while` at all here; perhaps you meant to do something like this?

```
for ((dt="$from"; dt <= "$to"; dt+=30)); do
    : something with "$dt"
done
```

The substring slicing with `${variable:start:length}` and the three-argument `for` loop are Bash features and not portable to other shells; and the `date -d` option is specific to GNU `date`.

Finally, [don't use upper case for your private variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

Comment: Your loop will iterate every 30 seconds using Unix epoch. Looping Epoch is good enough up to week scale, as it is a constant interval (ignoring leap second). For monthly or  yearly, this will not work though.

Comment: Yeah, I just put _something_ because it's not at all clear what the OP is actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have GNU awk for time functions, which would execute in about 2/3 of the time of the following, then using GNU `date` (to convert a timestamp to seconds since the epoch) and bash 4.2 or laters `printf '%(...)T'` (to convert seconds since the epoch to a timestamp) to loop through a timestamp range 10 seconds at a time, for example, would be:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

beg=20231205203830
end=20231205203950

ts2secs() {
    [[ $1 =~ (....)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..) ]] &&
        date -d "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}-${BASH_REMATCH[2]}-${BASH_REMATCH[3]} ${BASH_REMATCH[4]}:${BASH_REMATCH[5]}:${BASH_REMATCH[6]}" +'%s'
}

begSecs=$(ts2secs "$beg")
endSecs=$(ts2secs "$end")

for (( curSecs="$begSecs"; curSecs<="$endSecs"; curSecs+=10 )); do
    printf -v curTs '%(%Y%m%d%H%M%S)T' "$curSecs"
    printf '%s -> %s\n' "$curSecs" "$curTs"
done
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
1701830310 -> 20231205203830
1701830320 -> 20231205203840
1701830330 -> 20231205203850
1701830340 -> 20231205203900
1701830350 -> 20231205203910
1701830360 -> 20231205203920
1701830370 -> 20231205203930
1701830380 -> 20231205203940
1701830390 -> 20231205203950
```

If you don't have GNU date then see [Convert a date string to EPOCH time with POSIX tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74159180/convert-a-date-string-to-epoch-time-with-posix-tools/74159952#74159952) for a POSIX way to convert a date to seconds since the epoch.

Unlike calling `printf -v`, calling `date` in a loop would be extremely slow so avoid doing that if possible, see the time comparisons further down this answer, which is why we only convert from seconds to timestamps within the above loop, not the other direction.

Lots more details, considerations, and scripts below....

Using GNU awk for time functions (`mktime()`, `strftime()`) plus `gensub()` and `switch()`:

```
$ cat tst_awk
#!/usr/bin/env bash

prtRange() {
    awk -v beg="$1" -v end="$2" -v step="$3" 'BEGIN {
        switch(step) {
            case /d$/: stepSecs = step * 60 * 60 * 24 ; break
            case /h$/: stepSecs = step * 60 * 60      ; break
            case /m$/: stepSecs = step * 60           ; break
            default:   stepSecs = step + 0            ; break
        }

        begSecs = mktime(gensub(/(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)$/," \\1 \\2 \\3 \\4 \\5",1,beg))
        endSecs = mktime(gensub(/(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)$/," \\1 \\2 \\3 \\4 \\5",1,end))

        for ( curSecs=begSecs; curSecs<=endSecs; curSecs+=stepSecs ) {
            print curSecs, strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S",curSecs)
        }

        # Consider the case where the range is not evenly divided by the step size
        if ( (curSecs - stepSecs) != endSecs ) {
            print endSecs, strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S",endSecs)
        }
    }'
}

beg="$1"
end="$2"
step="$3"

while IFS= read -r timestamp; do
    echo "$timestamp"
done < <( prtRange "$beg" "$end" "$step" )
```

```
$ ./tst_awk 20231205203845 20231205204000 10
1701830325 20231205203845
1701830335 20231205203855
1701830345 20231205203905
1701830355 20231205203915
1701830365 20231205203925
1701830375 20231205203935
1701830385 20231205203945
1701830395 20231205203955
1701830400 20231205204000
```

The 3rd parameter is the step size, if it ends in `d` such as `2d` then it's specified in days, `h` hours, `m` minutes and anything else (or nothing) is seconds. Hopefully it's obvious how to add any other step size.

Obviously change the `print` statements in the `awk` script to print whatever version of the timestamp you want.

You need to decide what to do when the range from the beginning to the end timestamp does not divide evenly by the step size - in the above I decided to manually print the specified end time which is why there's 5 seconds instead of 10 between the last 2 output times but of course you could decide to end 1 iteration before the specified end timestamp, or 1 iteration after it, or recalculate the step size so it's close to the argument passed in but does divide [close to] evenly or whatever else you want to do to handle that case.

Here is an equivalent to the above but using `date` instead of `awk` to manipulate the timestamps:

```
$ cat tst_date
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ts2secs() {
    [[ $1 =~ (....)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..) ]] &&
    date -d \
        "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}-${BASH_REMATCH[2]}-${BASH_REMATCH[3]} ${BASH_REMATCH[4]}:${BASH_REMATCH[5]}:${BASH_REMATCH[6]}" \
        +'%s'
}

secs2ts() {
    date -d "@$1" +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S'
}

prtRange() {
    local beg=$1 end=$2 step=$3 stepSfx='s' begSecs endSecs stepSecs curSteps

    stepSfx="${step//[0-9]/}"
    step="${step//[^0-9]/}"

    case $stepSfx in
        d ) stepSecs=$(( step * 60 * 60 * 24 )) ;;
        h ) stepSecs=$(( step * 60 * 60      )) ;;
        m ) stepSecs=$(( step * 60           )) ;;
        * ) stepSecs=$(( step + 0            )) ;;
    esac

    begSecs=$( ts2secs "$beg" )
    endSecs=$( ts2secs "$end" )

    for (( curSecs=begSecs; curSecs<=endSecs; curSecs+=stepSecs )); do
        curTs=$( secs2ts "$curSecs" )
        printf '%s %s\n' "$curSecs" "$curTs"
    done

    # Consider the case where the range is not evenly divided by the step size
    if (( (curSecs - stepSecs) != endSecs )); then
        endTs=$( secs2ts "$endSecs" )
        printf '%s %s\n' "$endSecs" "$endTs"
    fi
}

beg="$1"
end="$2"
step="$3"

while IFS= read -r timestamp; do
    echo "$timestamp"
done < <( prtRange "$beg" "$end" "$step" )
```

```
$ ./tst_date 20231205203845 20231205204000 10
1701830325 20231205203845
1701830335 20231205203855
1701830345 20231205203905
1701830355 20231205203915
1701830365 20231205203925
1701830375 20231205203935
1701830385 20231205203945
1701830395 20231205203955
1701830400 20231205204000
```

so as you can see it produces the same output, but look at the time difference if we give the 2 scripts a larger number of iterations, e.g. a 1 hour range, 10 seconds at a time:

```
$ time ./tst_date 20231205000000 20231205010000 10 | wc -l
361

real    0m58.721s
user    0m0.138s
sys     0m0.498s
```

```
$ time ./tst_awk 20231205000000 20231205010000 10 | wc -l
361

real    0m0.533s
user    0m0.152s
sys     0m0.606s
```

They produced the same output again but the `date` version took about 1 minute to run while the `awk` version took about half a second.

Luckily there is a much faster way to do this in bash 4.2 and later thanks to it's builtin `printf` having a `T` formatting option to convert seconds from the epoch to timestamp formats:

```
$ cat tst_printf
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ts2secs() {
    [[ $1 =~ (....)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..) ]] &&
    date -d \
        "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}-${BASH_REMATCH[2]}-${BASH_REMATCH[3]} ${BASH_REMATCH[4]}:${BASH_REMATCH[5]}:${BASH_REMATCH[6]}" \
        +'%s'
}

secs2ts() {  # not actually being used here
    # date -d "@$1" +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S'
    printf '%(%Y%m%d%H%M%S)T\n' "$1"
}

prtRange() {
    local beg=$1 end=$2 step=$3 stepSfx='s' begSecs endSecs stepSecs curSteps

    stepSfx="${step//[0-9]/}"
    step="${step//[^0-9]/}"

    case $stepSfx in
        d ) stepSecs=$(( step * 60 * 60 * 24 )) ;;
        h ) stepSecs=$(( step * 60 * 60      )) ;;
        m ) stepSecs=$(( step * 60           )) ;;
        * ) stepSecs=$(( step + 0            )) ;;
    esac

    begSecs=$( ts2secs "$beg" )
    endSecs=$( ts2secs "$end" )

    for (( curSecs=begSecs; curSecs<=endSecs; curSecs+=stepSecs )); do
        # curTs=$( secs2ts "$curSecs" )
        printf -v curTs '%(%Y%m%d%H%M%S)T' "$curSecs"
        printf '%s %s\n' "$curSecs" "$curTs"
    done

    # Consider the case where the range is not evenly divided by the step size
    if (( (curSecs - stepSecs) != endSecs )); then
        # endTs=$( secs2ts "$endSecs" )
        printf -v endTs '%(%Y%m%d%H%M%S)T' "$endSecs"
        printf '%s %s\n' "$endSecs" "$endTs"
    fi
}

beg="$1"
end="$2"
step="$3"

while IFS= read -r timestamp; do
    echo "$timestamp"
done < <( prtRange "$beg" "$end" "$step" )
```

```
$ ./tst_printf 20231205203845 20231205204000 10
1701830325 20231205203845
1701830335 20231205203855
1701830345 20231205203905
1701830355 20231205203915
1701830365 20231205203925
1701830375 20231205203935
1701830385 20231205203945
1701830395 20231205203955
1701830400 20231205204000
```

```
$ time ./tst_printf 20231205000000 20231205010000 10 | wc -l
361

real    0m0.714s
user    0m0.292s
sys     0m0.667s
```

which is very close to the performance from the version using `awk`.

I'm printf-ing the timestamp directly to the variable using `-v` because doing the assignment from a function call (commented out in the above script) changes the execution time from about 3/4 of a second to almost 30 seconds, presumably due to the subshell spawned by `$(...)` when you execute a command that way. There is no change I could come up with that could noticeably speed up the `date` version of the script.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using a scripting language (g?awk, Python, Perl, Ruby, etc) to generate the time interval strings.

Here is an example with Ruby that demonstrates parsing and/or producing your format:

```
#!/bin/bash

start_date='20231205203830'
end_date='20231206203830'
time_inc='7203' # each interval is 2:03

ruby -r date -e '
inp=$<.read.split
DateTime.parse(inp[0]).step(DateTime.parse(inp[1]), 
   Rational(inp[2].to_i, 86400)){|e| 
      puts "#{e} => #{e.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")}"}
' <(echo "$start_date $end_date $time_inc")
```

Prints:

```
2023-12-05T20:38:30+00:00 => 20231205203830
2023-12-05T22:38:33+00:00 => 20231205223833
2023-12-06T00:38:36+00:00 => 20231206003836
2023-12-06T02:38:39+00:00 => 20231206023839
2023-12-06T04:38:42+00:00 => 20231206043842
2023-12-06T06:38:45+00:00 => 20231206063845
2023-12-06T08:38:48+00:00 => 20231206083848
2023-12-06T10:38:51+00:00 => 20231206103851
2023-12-06T12:38:54+00:00 => 20231206123854
2023-12-06T14:38:57+00:00 => 20231206143857
2023-12-06T16:39:00+00:00 => 20231206163900
2023-12-06T18:39:03+00:00 => 20231206183903
```

You can then use a Bash `while` loop to read the strings generated for each interval:

```
while read -r ts; do
    echo "$ts"
done < <(echo "$start_date $end_date $time_inc" | ruby -r date -e '
inp=$<.read.split
DateTime.parse(inp[0]).step(DateTime.parse(inp[1]), 
        Rational(inp[2].to_i, 86400)){|e| puts "#{e.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")}"}')
```

(Probably even better still to replace that entire Bash loop with something in a scripting language...)